# How to count length

Tags: angularjs

if Entered  Email length count>0 comeses in else out please suggest me where i'm doing mistake

```
 $scope.CheckEmail = function () {
        var x = {
            Email: $scope.Email
        }
        if (x.length >= 0) {
            var check = MyService.ChkMail(x);
            check.then(function (d) {
                $scope.Valid = d.data;
            })
        }
```

Comment: use `x.Email.length` instance of `x.length`

Comment: and later on replace `x` with `x.Email`

Answer (score 1):

u need to access the **Email** property of the x object

```
if (x.Email.length >= 0) {
 var check = MyService.ChkMail(x);
            check.then(function (d) {
                $scope.Valid = d.data;
            })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use following -

```
$scope.CheckEmail = function () {
        var x = {
            Email: $scope.Email
        }
        if (x.Email.length >= 0) {
            var check = MyService.ChkMail(x);
            check.then(function (d) {
                $scope.Valid = d.data;
            })
        }
```

Hope this will work..

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning x to an object. Therefore `x.length` will always return `undefined`. You can assign x directly to your scope variable:

```
$scope.CheckEmail = function () {
    var x = $scope.Email;
    if (x.length >= 0) {
        var check = MyService.ChkMail(x);
        check.then(function (d) {
            $scope.Valid = d.data;
        })

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check length > 0 , I would suggest to use the `required` attribute on your input, and then check your form with angular like

```
<form name="form" novaldiate>
    <input type="email" ng-model="Email" name="Email" required>
</form>
```

Then you can check :

Is this is a valid Email ? `{{form.Email.$valid}}`

(easier if you email come from a form)